# "have no pig in the race": is it an idiom?

Tags: idioms

Below is an excerpt from [an essay](https://lithub.com/oh-good-tiktok-is-breaking-into-bookselling/) on Literary Hub:

> It was sweet that readers who **have absolutely no pig in the race** would care so much about a story that they wanted to shout it from the rooftops.

I have never come across this alleged idiom, so I turned to OED but to no avail. Results from COCA for "no pig" are rather immaterial, too. Then I searched Google for "no pig in the race", to find out that there seems to be something like pig-racing in North Carolina State Fair, but nothing relevant to the usage in the above sentence.

I was a little confused. The author of the essay above used this expression like it was an idiom, but I reckon there should be some steps away from "unfamiliar phrases you can guess upon" to an easily recognizable idiom.

Comment: Search again for "no dog in the race" or "no horse in the race". It means the same as "no skin in the game".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct is correct, and the author is apparently being facetious. The actual idiom is "have no horse in this race". [From The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+horse+in+this+race):

> A phrase said when one is not invested in or affected by the outcome of something.

I haven't looked at your link, so I don't know the context of that sentence, but presumably there is some reason why the author changed "horse" to "pig".

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that a native speaker would have no trouble with 'I have absolutely no creature in the race'.